# Wia 2.0 Дуплексное сканирование бросает исключение System.outofmemoryException

Tags: c#, wia, сканирование

Я использую WIA + C#

Чтобы включить AFD и дуплексное сканирование устанавливаю свойства:

***pages*** = 1 , ***documenthandlingselect*** = 5

получаю исключение ***System.OutOfMemoryExcepion*** в методе ***wiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer***

Кто-нибудь можете помочь мне исправить это?
Правильные ли я использую значения?

```
try
{
     SetWIAProperty(device.Properties, "3096", 1);//pages to 1
     SetWIAProperty(device.Properties,"3088",5);//Handling select to 5
     if (init == false)
     {
          init = true;
     }
     wiaCommonDialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();
     while (true)
     {
          object imgFile = (ImageFile)wiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(item,
            WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG,false); // <== Here the exception is shown
          object imgFile2=(ImageFile)wiaCommonDialog.ShowTransfer(item, 
            WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG, false);
          if (imgFile != null)
          {
               imagenes.Add((ImageFile)imgFile);
               leyo = true;
          }
          if (imgFile2 != null)
          {
               imagenes.Add((ImageFile)imgFile2);
               leyo = true;
          }
     }
}
```

Аналогичный вопрос на англоязычном stackoverflow: [Wia 2.0 duplex scanning throw exception “System.outofmemoryException” C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53507453/wia-2-0-duplex-scanning-throw-exception-system-outofmemoryexception-c-sharp)

Comment: Так тут же бесконечный цикл

Comment: @yolosora верно. и этот цикл не может завершиться даже первый раз. при одностороннем с feeder сканировании 10+ листов = ок, при двухстороннем = падение на второй стороне первого листа.

Answer (score -1):

Вы в цикле постоянно создаете объекты `imgFile` и `imgFile2` и добавляете из в коллекцию `imagenes`. Все это сидит в памяти. Очищайте коллекцию по какому-то условию.

Comment: в эту коллекцию удается отсканировать 10+ односторонних листов а при сканировании в двухстороннем режиме падает на второй стороне первого листа.

Answer (score -1):

Если вы уверены что у вас есть достаточного количесво памяти и это не связано с бесконечным сыклом, на то есть другое решение.

1) Если вы используете 32-битную Windows, у вас будет доступно только 2 ГБ памяти.

2) Не забывайте, что базовая реализация `List`- это массив. Если ваша память сильно фрагментирована, может быть недостаточно непрерывного пространства для ее выделения, даже если в целом у вас достаточно свободной памяти.

3) Если вы уверены, что у вас достаточно свободной памяти, работает на 64-битной ОС и все еще получает исключения, обязательно установите этот параметр в свойствах вашего проекта

[image: Свойство проекта]

Comment: спасибо, но дело не совсем в памяти... при при одностороннем с feeder сканировании памяти хватает на 10+ страниц при включении дуплекса сканирует первую сторону первой страницы и падает исключение нехватка памяти. мы тут думаем проблема в чем-то чему не хватает памяти при включении двухстороннего сканирования сканирования.